# Changing property of a value in a list without changing the value itself

Tags: c#, winforms, list, properties

I have a list with values in it (These are types from a class Class1). Every single value has a Date property in it. Now I'm trying this when one element gets added to the list:

```
 var entry = list.First();
            list.Add(entry);
            list.First().DateVal = new DateTime(list.First().DateVal.Value.Year,1,1);
```

So I'm copying the element and changing the property DateVal to 01.01.xxxx. What happens is that it also changes the whole value to 01.01.xxxx. This happens for both values. Example:

value: 05.10. property: 05.10.2015

After that I get:

value: 01.01. property: 01.01.2015
value: 01.01. property: 01.01.2015

What I want is:

value: 05.10. property: 01.01.2015
value: 05.10. property: 05.10.2015

How to just Change the property? I'm wondering why the Code above does not work.

Comment: So you are taking the first entry in the list adding it then you want to set the value of the one you have just put in?

Comment: Yes. I'm copying the first element and then I want to change the property of the first one but the whole value gets changed. I want to keep both elements and just have the Date property of the first one changed to 1.1.xxxx

Comment: Ok so I'm still not entirely sure of what you're looking for. Do you want to change the original one or the copy, or doesn't it matter? Also is the issue that when you change one it changes the date in both?

Comment: I described it a little bit better. Hope now it's clear

Comment: So, looking at that you want to change a property without changing its values which isn't possible as they are directly dependant on each other. Where do the value and property values come from? Could you post up the code for the class that is used for the objects in the list? also, the reason both dates change is that you are adding the same object to the list twice, not cloning it.

Comment: we need more details, can you give us the class1 code (which by the way is very unclear what it is) and give more info overall?

Comment: That's a bit complicated. The whole structure is complicated too. It's a property within the class which gets the Date. One can set the Date by entering Year,Month,Day as Integer. So it's not possible? Why do both values change when I just change the property of the first one?

Comment: @Jackson30 I have given two different approaches in my answer to account for updating either the original or new object. This is as best as I can do with the limited information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for updating the new objects property?

```
var original = list.First();
var newObject = new Class1(){
        DateVal = original.DateVal,
        //Set other properties
    };
    newObject.DateVal = new DateTime(newObject.DateVal.Value.Year, 1, 1);
    list.Add(newObject);
```

The reason that both dates change when you change one is that you are just adding the same object to the list twice, you are not copying it. So when you change one it changes the other. Not sure if your expected output is a typo but it suggests you want the value and the property on a single object to have a different value, I assume the value and the property cannot be different because they are the same thing. Using MemberwiseClone() on the object should clone and solve the issue of both element changing their date when you update one though. Also, assuming you want to change the one you have created then this changes it before you add it instead of looking in the list for it again and again. If you want to change the original then try this:

```
var original = list.First();
var newObject = new Class1(){
        DateVal = original.DateVal,
        //Set other properties
    };
    original.DateVal = new DateTime(original.DateVal.Value.Year, 1, 1);
    list.Add(newObject);
```

This clones the object then updates the original without looking in the list again.

Comment: Can't Access protected method MemberwiseClone here - Ok I have to implement it first. I will do and then try it again

Comment: I need to implement ICloneable into my Interface. Doesn't this clone every single property etc then? Like Primary Keys and so on? Isn't it better to create a new object and set it's properties?

Comment: You can create a new object an set all properties, it would do the same thing. I have edited it to copy the object manually

Comment: That helps! Thank you very much!